# Why we have central versions like 2.4.0-b180725.0427 and 2.4.0-b180830.0359 in javax.xml.bind » jaxb-api dependecy?

Tags: java, jaxb

[image]

2.4.0-b180725.0427 and 2.4.0-b180830.0359 looks stable but I want to understand why we have versions like *-b*?
Can we use these version in production environment?

Comment: I would stay with the 2.3.1 version as it is the latest release (regarding release date). For more details see the source code: https://github.com/javaee/jaxb-spec